# SQL Server concatenate column based on case statement

Tags: sql-server, concatenation, case

I have a select statement where I'm getting results like this

| S_ID | CODE | C_DESC | CODE_A | C_A_DESC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 83597 | PE | PE | PEONESTR | PE ONE STAR |
| 83597 | CE | CE | CEONE | CE ONE STAR |
| 83597 | CE | CE | CERWO | CE TWO STAR |
| 83597 | RG | RG | RGONE | RG ONE STAR |

Looking for result like this, when the column code has multiple entries and code specific to 'CE', I want to concatenate the last two columns

| S_ID | CODE | C_DESC | CODE_A | C_A_DESC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 83597 | PE | PE | PEONESTR | PE ONE STAR |
| 83597 | CE | CE | CEONE, CETWO | CE ONE STAR, CE TWO STAR |
| 83597 | RG | RG | RGONE | RG ONE STAR |

What would be the best way to achieve that? Thanks in advance

Comment: use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: ```select S_ID,CODE, C_DESC,string_agg(CODE_A,',' ) CODE_A,string_agg(C_A_DESC,',') C_A_DESC from table
group by  S_ID,CODE, C_DESC```

Answer (score 1):

If your using SQL Server 2017 (14.x) or later you can use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SELECT S_ID,CODE, 
     C_DESC,
     STRING_AGG(CODE_A,',' ) CODE_A,
     STRING_AGG(C_A_DESC,',') C_A_DESC 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY S_ID,CODE, C_DESC
```

For earlier versions:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table   t  
WHERE CODE <> 'CE'

UNION ALL

SELECT S_ID,
    CODE,   
    C_DESC,   
    STUFF ((select ', ' + CODE_A from your_table  where S_ID = t.S_ID AND C_DESC = t.C_DESC  AND CODE = t.CODE  for xml path('')),1,2,'') AS CODE_A,   
    STUFF ((select ', ' + C_A_DESC from your_table  where S_ID = t.S_ID AND C_DESC = t.C_DESC  AND CODE = t.CODE for xml path('')),1,2,'') AS C_A_DESC  
FROM your_table   t 
WHERE CODE = 'CE'
GROUP BY S_ID,
    CODE,   
    C_DESC
```

Comment: Unfortunately STRING_AGG isn't a supported in my SQL instance. I just need the concatenation only when code is 'CE'. Maybe a case statement?

Comment: @Eclipse i edited my response with the query for earlier version.